# How to use color images for Tensorflow image classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following a [Tensorflow image classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) tutorial which uses the Fashion MNIST data set.  Each image is a 28x28 grey scale image:

```
train_images[0].shape
(28, 28)
```

...which later in the tutorial is normalized and fed it into a Flatten layer.

```
train_images = train_images / 255.0
# ...
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

I have a data set of color PNGs that I've imported using matplotlib that have a shape of:

```
(400, 400, 3)
```

Given the different shape of the images (28,28) vs (400, 400, 3), how can I adapt the classifier to use it...without converting to grey scale?

Comment: You need to change to `keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(400, 400,3))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small example:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(400, 400, 3)),
keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,strides=(1,1),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,strides=(2,2),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,strides=(1,1),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,strides=(2,2),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(128,kernel_size=3,strides=(1,1),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(128,kernel_size=3,strides=(2,2),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(256,kernel_size=3,strides=(1,1),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(256,kernel_size=3,strides=(2,2),activation='relu', padding='same'),
keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

])

Or you can use pretrain model from `keras.applications`:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(400,400,3)) 
x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(10,activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(base_model.input,x)
```

Comment: I dont need to normalize the data in some way first?  Like images / 255.0?

Comment: Of course, just like your normalization method is OK. Because value of pixel in each channel is in [0, 255].

Comment: Does that mean, for color images, we need to flatten them first and then apply conv layers? But then it would be a vector of dim 480000x1, so how will conv layer (filter of size 3x3) work? Also, padding = 'same' means no padding?

Comment: I'm a beginner & I've seen max-pooling layers after every convolution layer. What's the intuition of replacing all max-pooling layers with just one 'GlobalAveragePooling2D layer' after all convolution layers?